# Dataflow update failure: The value corresponding to experiment use_shuffle_service_address could not be parsed from

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, autoscaling

I tried to update a streaming dataflow pipeline because it was not properly autoscaling in a consistent and speedy manner. The pipeline uses the shuffle service and returned the following error:  **The workflow could not be created due to misconfiguration. The value corresponding to experiment use_shuffle_service_address could not be parsed from.**

I already have set the number of workers at 5 and have the autoscaling algo set to THROUGHPUT_BASE, as well. The data volume when I first start my pipeline is low so the workers scale down to 1. However, when a lot more data comes in the scale up is to multiple workers is very slow and creates quite a bit of lag (up to 40 mins to scale up).

I want dataflow to either autoscale faster upon receiving a surge in data or I want to be able to update the pipeline and keep the shuffle service.

Comment: It will be good to reach dataflow customer support as this needs more information on data spike duration and investigation on cause of slow auto scaling. I would also recommend increasing the maxworker for your pipeline to let job get more room for expansion.

Comment: So this was an issue on their end. I reported.